# Since Windows now got Linux Subsystem is it possible to replace git bash/cygwin?

Tags: git

I don't understand why nobody seems to have looked at this: is it impossible?

I'm not expert at Linux, but I can't see the point of having a Linux subsystem on Windows if one continues to have to install Linux external modules on Windows.Could you please  help me

Comment: check what this subsystem is :) - it's just replicating some commands and it's not really a working linux ...

Comment: Nobody ever needed to install “Linux external modules” so I don’t understand the question. Git also works natively on Windows so that’s no reason either.

Comment: @drako Maybe you should check it out if you think it’s replicating or just “some commands”...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I checked it out about year and a half ago when it came out - even if its improved I still don't believe it's real useful functional system - I tested it and found useless, because for Win there are win tools and if I need linux I can have free Oracle Vbox with VM, and most of linux commands even ported to win work differently then you would be used to on nix so ... I don't see point using it (at least as it was spring 2016) - and I don't believe in big improvements in it - so I will not retest it now...

Comment: @drako *You* seeing no point for *yourself* doesn’t mean it’s just “some commands” or that you should tell people it’s useless *for them*, you know. It’s very useful and does a lot of things you can’t do with a VM. And as you said, commands ported work differently so why not use the actual commands then? Contradicting.

Comment: @Drako I think you should look at this again. You have a complete gnu/linux install. This is not just replicating a few linux commands. With 3rd party tools, you can even choose pretty much any distribution. Agreed, you do not have a linux kernel, somewhere under all this it is the Windows kernel, but all of the gnu tools are available and you can use apt/yum to install what you want. Yes, there are still complications interacting with Windows processes/applications, but it's pretty impressive and useful already.

Comment: @Mort - thanks, if it has evolved so much - then I take back my "anti-opinion" and will have a look at it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, yes, as soon as the linux subsystem is stable enough, installing cygwin or git bash over it can be considered redundant.

As you can see on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide), it allows you to use utility shell commands from it, run git, and more:

[image]

Since I'm not expert to cygwin, I can't say if cygwin suggest any extra features, so please feel free to point out any features that are missing from the linux subsystem.